# Interlocked.CompareExchange "short-circuit" evaluation

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I have just realized that I allocate a lot of objects in `Interlocked.CompareExchange` and throw them away to GC, because the value (second argument) is always evaluated, compared to `&&` or `||`, which use [`short-circuit` evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820610/is-relying-on-short-circuiting-safe-in-net) .

Is lock the only alternative to atomically check for null and allocate a new object only if the target location is `null`?

This test prints "I am created" three times and fails on the last assertion.

```
internal class TestCompareExchange {
    public static TestCompareExchange defalt = new TestCompareExchange();
    public static bool allocated = false;
    public TestCompareExchange() {
        allocated = true;
        Console.WriteLine("I am created");
    }
}

[Test]
public void CompareExchangeAllocatesValue() {

    if (TestCompareExchange.allocated && (new TestCompareExchange()) != null) // the second part after && is not evaluated 
    {

    }
    Assert.IsFalse(TestCompareExchange.allocated);

    TestCompareExchange target = null;
    var original = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref target, new TestCompareExchange(), (TestCompareExchange)null);
    Assert.AreEqual(null, original);
    Assert.IsTrue(TestCompareExchange.allocated);

    TestCompareExchange.allocated = false;
    target = null;
    original = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref target, new TestCompareExchange(), TestCompareExchange.defalt);
    Assert.AreEqual(null, original);
    Assert.IsFalse(TestCompareExchange.allocated); // no exchange, but objetc is allocated
}
```

In my real code, I use `TaskCompletionSource` instead of the fake object. Does it matter? Is there some pooling for TCS objects that makes allocation and collection irrelevant for them?

Comment: Have you considered using a `Lazy<T>`?

Comment: How `Lazy<T>` would help here if another thread uses `Interlocked.Exchange` to set the target to `null`?

Comment: As far as I understand it, you want to have only one instance of some class. *... atomically check for null and allocate a new object only if the target location is null?* That's what `Lazy<T>` does.

Comment: No, I want to have only one instance *at a point of time*. Several million times per second. It is like producer-consumer, but producer never produces a value until consumer consumes the single one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before performing the `Interlocked` operation and the allocation see if the target location is not null already. If yes, there is no need to try and initialize it.

`if (Volatile.Read(ref target) == null) InitAtomically();`

Comment: Great, haven't used `Volatile` class before. Thanks! This is exactly the answer.