# Using parameter in Linq that might be null

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method I am passing in two times, beginning and end.  The user can enter either, both, or none.  I then query the db using Linq to find all record between those two times.  How would I deal with the cases when beginning and or end parameters are null.  If neither are null than it is

```
where beginning <= time && time <= end
```

Is there a way to write these cases out without having to use an if, if else, else statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the input parameter is null OR if the input parameter matches the conditions.

```
// from and to are user DateTime? inputs
var filtered = myCollection.Where(x =>
    (from == null || x.Date >= from) &&
    (to == null || x.Date < to));
```

This works in every scenario...

- If the user enters no dates, all items are returned.
- If the user enters `from`, all items after `from` are returned.
- If the user enters `to`, all items before `to` are returned.
- If the user enters both `from` and `to`, all items between `from` and `to` are returned.

---

**Edit**

This works thanks to the `||` operator being short-circuiting. In my answer, if the optional parameters (`from` or `to`) are not specified (thus `null`) then the expression resolves true and the second condition is not even evaluated. However, if they are not null, then the second condition will be checked as well.

Here is a snippet from the C# spec which [I stole from this answer :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820618/3630637) that explains (probably better than I could) about short-circuiting operators.

> The `&&` and `||` operators are called the conditional logical operators. They are also called the “shortcircuiting” logical operators.
>
> ...
>
> The operation `x && y` corresponds to the operation `x & y`, except that `y` is evaluated only if `x` is `true`
> The operation `x || y` corresponds to the operation `x | y`, except that `y` is evaluated only if `x` is not `true`.
>
> ...
>
> The operation `x || y` is evaluated as `x ? true : y`. In other words, `x` is first evaluated and converted to type `bool`. Then, if `x` is `true`, the result of the operation is `true`. Otherwise, `y` is evaluated and converted to type `bool`, and this becomes the result of the operation.

Comment: To the uninitiated this looks like it might fail, perhaps you could explain why it works?

Comment: @DavidG Sure... This works because `||` and `&&` are short-circuiting in C#. [This answer has a bunch of information from the C# spec, which details how it works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4820618/3630637).

Comment: Put that in your answer, not in a comment! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small demonstration:

The logic expression that will fill your request was:

`(!start.HasValue || start < we.Reception) && (we.Reception < end || !end.HasValue)`

**Meaning:**

(If **start does not** have **value** TRUE **OR** (value smaller than ReceptionValue)) **AND** (**ReceptionValue** smaller than **end value** **OR** (end does not have value be TRUE))

```
var myTimes = new List<WeddingEvent>()
{
    new WeddingEvent { Id = 1, Reception = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3) },
    new WeddingEvent { Id = 2, Reception = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2) },
    new WeddingEvent { Id = 3, Reception = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1) },
    new WeddingEvent { Id = 4, Reception = DateTime.Now.AddHours(0) },
    new WeddingEvent { Id = 5, Reception = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1) },
    new WeddingEvent { Id = 6, Reception = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2) },
    new WeddingEvent { Id = 7, Reception = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3) },
};

DateTime? start = null; //DateTime.Now.AddHours(0.5);
DateTime? end = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3.5);
var weddingInHalfAnHour = myTimes.Where(we => (!start.HasValue || start < we.Reception) && (we.Reception < end || !end.HasValue));
foreach (var wedding in weddingInHalfAnHour)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} ReceptiontTime: {1}", wedding.Id, wedding.Reception);
}
```