# In if statement, if one of the parts separated by or returns true, will it continue the statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

If I have an if statement separated by `||` returns true, will it continue the statement?

for example: `if(true || random())`, will `random()` be executed? because there is no reason for that.

Comment: You should really look this type of stuff up first. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`random()` will *not* be executed:

> The conditional-OR operator (`||`) performs a logical-OR of its `bool` operands. If the first operand evaluates to `true`, the second operand isn't evaluated. If the first operand evaluates to `false`, the second operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to `true` or `false`.

See [|| Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820618/60188).

Comment: Is this answer valid for most new languages or only for c#?

Comment: Really depends on the language. VB (and VB.NET) do not, by default, do short-circuit evaluation (but do them when `And`/`Or` is replaced with `AndAlso`/`OrElse`

Answer (score 1):

No, `random()` will not be executed if you put `||` and your first condition is true.

However, with `|` both conditions get checked no matter what the first result is.