# .net CF 3.5 Remove() or RemoveAt() crashes application

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-mobile-5.0

I'm using .net CF 3.5 to develop an application for Windows Mobile 5.0

I have a ListBox with a list of numbers in. When they click on a number in the list, it should be deleted from the list. I can get the selected item's index just fine from the list - However, I cannot seem to delete it without the application crashing. There are no errors, it will just exit with code 0.

```
private void DeleteOrder(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string s = (string) orders_list.SelectedItem;
  int size = orders_list.Items.Count;


  bool con = true;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Debug.Write("\nIS: " + i + "\n");
    if (con) {
      if (s != null || s != "") {
        if (orders_list.GetItemText(orders_list.Items[i]) != null) {
          if (orders_list.GetItemText(orders_list.Items[i]).ToString() == s) {
            if (orders_list.Items[i] != null) {
              Debug.Write("ORDER IS : " + orders_list.Items[i].ToString());
              orders_list.Items.Remove(orders_list.Items[i].ToString());
            }

            con = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  input_scan.Text = "";
  this.BackColor = Color.Lime;

  input_scan.Focus();
}
}
}
```

As you can see, I've tried doing

```
orders_list.Items.Remove(orders_list.Items[i].ToString());
```

to see if I can remove the string object and I've tried using `RemoveAt()` to remove by index, but each time the application will keep crashing.

Any help would be appreciated as something so simple such as removing from a collection has become rather a challenge.

Comment: I strongly suspect that an exception is being thrown. You need to find out what that exception is.

Comment: `if(a) if(b) if (c) if (d) { }` if better formulated as `if(a && b && c && d) {}`. Because C# does a [Short-Circuit Evaluation (c-sharpcorner)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/short-circuit-evaluation-in-c-sharp/), both perform with equal efficency. Se also: [&& Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator) and [Is relying on && short-circuiting safe in .NET? (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820610/is-relying-on-short-circuiting-safe-in-net).

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? If you wrap the logic in a try/catch, you can log the details.

Comment: The way this function is called is missing. Possibly you are trying a cross thread operation, which is not allowed (but the exception message is missing). You may need to use a dlegate to remove the Item.

Comment: This is incredibly odd but I have thrown the method into a Try/Catch and it appears to work flawlessly without any issues described above. Thank you to @virusstorm for suggesting this. I'll mark as solved and update my answer.

Comment: @ConnorBrady The try/catch just prevents the error from crashing your application. You still need to get to the root cause of the exception if you want to fix your application correctly.