# Short circuit with TryParse() and out variable reliable?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

This subject has been discussed many times and is clear: [Is relying on && short-circuiting safe in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820610/is-relying-on-short-circuiting-safe-in-net)

What I cannot find is a clear answer if the short circuit is also reliable when  `out` parameter is used in the right part of the `if` clause:

```
int foo;
....
if ( false == Int32.TryParse( bar, out foo ) || 0 == foo )
```

When I try this code then it works. But I am just a bit worried if the behavior is reliable, because I don't know how the compiler is translating the code and accessing `foo`.

**My question:**

Is the access to `foo` really done **after** the `TryParse` which would consider any changed value or the compiler can sometimes *read* the value **before** `TryParse` [because of some optimizations] and therefore I cannot rely on this code.

Comment: Unless there's a bug on the C# compiler, it will work, if there were a possibility of the variable being accessed before being assigned then the compiler would complain about it.

Comment: @Steve The 2nd condition is very necessary **when** it could be successfully parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the access to foo really done after the TryParse which would
>   consider any changed value

Yes, this will be the case.

> or the compiler can sometimes read the value before TryParse [because
>   of some optimizations] and therefore I cannot rely on this code.

No, it will not read `foo`  before the call to `Int32.TryParse`; one being that the logical OR will always evaluate the left side and *only* evaluates the right side if it's necessary. two, it will not evaluate the right side first because the `foo` variable is not initialised at that point which would cause a compilation error (assuming it's a local variable).

Comment: The point is that `foo` is a class member and therefore the compiler never warns regarding uninitialized variable - does it change anything?

Comment: @AlBundy doesn't change anything in terms of how the expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

You can verify this works by using the new language features in C#:

```
if (!int.TryParse("0", out int foo) || foo == 0)
{
    //foo == 0 or the tryparse failed
    //foo still exists here though, so if it fails, it will still == 0
}
```

You can see that the declaration of `foo` happens inside the `int.TryParse` call, which wouldn't happen if `foo == 0` was evaluated first. This is legal syntax in C# 7 and up. Really this is all syntactic sugar for this:

```
int foo = 0   
if (!int.TryParse("0", out foo) || foo == 0)
{
    //foo == 0 or the tryparse failed
}
```

Comment: I like this explanation but unfortunately I am stick to an old C# version due to the used framework.

Comment: @AlBundy The framework version and the language version are independent, you can use C# 7.1 and compile against .NET 2.0 if you want.

Comment: :-) - I am developing for [NinjaTrader 7](https://ninjatrader.com/support/forum/showpost.php?p=404820&postcount=2) and I have to use the C# compiler they provide :-((