# Check availability of values inside JSON objects using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I'm currently (de-)serializing JSON objects via System.Text.Json (.NET 6), but failing to easily verify if a some of the optional classes are present and if they contain values.

My structure looks like this:

```
class Request
{
    public string RequestID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

```
class User
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public bool? SomeOptionalBoolean { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON object (string) is deserialized to an object that contains the `Request` object. However, `Request` may not contain a `User` object which would raise a NPE when accessing it anyway. Therefore, I'm currently checking each class and its properties for `null` values when accessing the object's properties (like `request.User.UserID`):

```
internal static bool IsUserValid(Request request)
{
    if (request.User == null || request.User.UserID == null || request.User.Username == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (IsUserValid(request))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(request.User.UserID);
    }
}
```

This enables me to safely access the required properties, but it seems tedious and there's probably something I'm missing. How can I simplify this approach without writing validations for each and every class?

I've tried to search for solutions (like JsonRequired attributes) in Google and Stack Overflow, but couldn't find a pattern that matches my use case.

Comment: *I've tried to search for solutions (like **JsonRequired** attributes) ... but **couldn't find a pattern that matches my use case.*** -- why did [`[JsonRequired]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonrequiredattribute?view=net-7.0) (or any of the other options from MSFT's documentation page [Required properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/required-properties)) not meet your needs?

Comment: Also, if you just want to avoid null reference exceptions, you can use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-): `request?.User?.UserID`.

Comment: @dbc OP states that .NET 6 is used and docs say that `JsonRequired` is part of .NET 7

Comment: Thank you, I think you answered all my questions! Guess I need to upgrade to .NET 7 now and just use the null conditional operator to access the class.

Comment: @roccne JFYI null-conditional does not require .NET update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this a bit by using null propagation (via [null conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)):

```cs
static bool IsUserValid(Request request)
{
    var user = request.User;
    if (user?.UserID is null // if user is null will short-circuit the rest, so NREin following statements
        || user.Username is null
        || user.SomeOptionalBoolean is null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If you are willing to sacrifice performance a bit (no [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820618/2501279), some additional allocations including potential boxing) you can collect all properties into a single collection and use `Any`:

```cs
static bool IsUserValid(Request request)
{
    var user = request.User;
    var objects = new object?[]{user?.UserID, user?.Username, user?.SomeOptionalBoolean};
    if (objects.Any(o => o is null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Also if you can migrate to .NET 7 you can look into marking properties as required - check out [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/required-properties) (exception will be thrown on deserialization if any of required properties is missing).

Another approach is using JSON Schema to validate the json, for example via packages from [json-everything](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a collection of `Request` or `User` but as you said this is tedious to writing validations for each and every class. So going with the example you provided you can write and add [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for `Request` which will tie the validation method to the class:

```cs
public static class Extension
{
    public static bool IsUserValid(this Request request)
    {
        return request.User != null ? (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.User.UserID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.User.Username)): false;
    }
    
    public static void PrintValidUser(this Request request)
    {
        if(IsUserValid(request))
            Console.WriteLine(request.User.UserID);
    }
}
```

I have modified the above code to check for null/empty since it is a string also it will check for both the fields with `&&`.

Then use it the main the way  you like:

```cs
void Main()
{
    //request
    var request = new Request() { 
        User = new User(){ UserID = "roccne12345",Username = "roccne" } 
    };

    if (request.IsUserValid())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(request.User.UserID);
    }
    
   //or
    request.PrintValidUser();
}
```