# Is .NET compiler allowed to optimize `bool result = someMethod() || true` to `bool result = true`?

Tags: c#, .net

Based on [documetation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-) I understand that

```cs
bool result = someMethod() || true;
```

**cannot** be optimized by the .NET compiler to

```cs
bool result = true; // (or actually inlined)
```

To phrase it differently, my understanding is that `someMethod()` is always executed.

Is that correct? I'm just looking for a confirmation.

Comment: You'd have to open a Github issue in the .NET repo if you want confirmation. You're asking how the JIT compiler, not the C# compiler, would optimize this. You can use [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxBAzmAPgAQEwEYCwAUEZgMwAEO5AwuQN5HlOUWYAs5AsgBQCU9jZkOAB7EQBtyAJwCmKAK7iE5ALzkUIsDM4yEACxEATPuXTpyCKfJkBuQUKaZcATm6yFS3ncIPm98gC+/v6iEuqa2roGxrz+DD6+lADs5ABKEDCGmgB0AMp6ELKG2QByMgAeCCYApOTYKioADDaJ5P5BhAFAA===) to check the generated code, IL *and* assembly, which shows that even in Release the method is called

Comment: And indeed, why are you asking this? Is this an idiom copied from another language? There are probably better ways to do whatever you want to do

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because then it would *never* be called, so you might as well remove it entirely.

Comment: Language specification isn't explicit on this so you presumably have to look at the source of the compiler or the generated source for this example. But the language specification specifies that those operators are **left-associative** so your understanding is presumably correct.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: if both sides need to be evaluated always, use logical OR `|`

Comment: The compiler can't just remove the call because the method may have side-effects. If this is an attempt to create a feature flag, it won't work. There are ways to create a functional feature flag, just not this way

Comment: Another stupid question - what's the point of this code? since `result` will always be `true`, why use it at all? why not simply call `SomeMethod()` without even bothering to check it's return value?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I’m aware, but that isn’t what my comment is about (and *please* don’t use `|` if you want to evaluate both sides of the expression; instead, split it apart!).

Comment: Are you referring to the C# compiler (into IL) or the JIT compiler (into assembly)?

Comment: This has to do with short-circuiting. [In C#, both && and || short-circuit on the left *only*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820610/is-relying-on-short-circuiting-safe-in-net). This [Sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoTCDMACZPAYTwG9M9KD8EAWPAWQAoBKMiqz4Ae24Bs8AJwCmAZwCufAC54AvHimDxwvHDh5R3MMIbCpAC24ATVngDcHTpQQoAnExETpLCxitVLeAL6fPPfhpaOnqGJiye5G7uBADseABKEDBGWgB0AMr6ECJGqQBywgAeUqYApHhIsrIADGbReJ4+GF5AA===) example shows that `true ||..` short-circuits

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's not true what you said at the top, the method is inlined by the JIT. You can see if you force inlining off https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxBAzmAPgAQEwEYCwAUJgAwAEmuAdAEoCuMCUYAplQMID2YADlADYsATgGVhANygBjFigDcRIpgDMFbGXZkA3kTJ6KqzABYyAWQAUASm279d4J078yQ2XX4IyAXjIpuLUxYEAAtOABMrMnR0MgQhOhYFQjs7SgBOc1cUdwRLJJT9Wz0AXyKyMoBtQJDwgElefnNq0LD6nn4AeR4mThgUKgA5TlqYflhYAHNLAF0yhydff2bwqzKdZIKKAHYyGggYMO4qEWCIVzDBlgAPBEiAUjJsLy8SOU3yjZKiYqA===

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And forced on https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxBAzmAPgAQEwEYCwAUJgAwAEmuAdAEoCuMCUYAplQMID2YADlADYsATgGVhANygBjFigDcRIpgDMFbGXZkA3kTJ6KqzABYyAWQAUASm279d4J078yQ2XX4IyAXjIpuLUxYEAAtOABMrMnR0MgQhOhYFQjs7SgBOc1cUdwRLJJT9Wz0AXyKyMoBtQJDwgElefnNq0LD6nn4AeR4mThgUKgBBAHMhrJQocRZamH5YWCHLAF0yhydff2bwqzKdZIKKAHYyGggYMO4qEWCIVzCqADkWAA8ESIBSMmwvLxI5ffK9iUiMUgA=== But you're right the C# compiler itself only inlines `true ||`

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I don't know if this is the OP's scenario, but as an example, I have tons of auto-generated parser code with this pattern for parsing out optional features.

Comment: @Charlieface I wasn't talking about inlining. Inlining means the call is still made.

Comment: It does in general not make much sense to ponder "always executed", given that the jitter optimizer tries hard to not execute methods.  Optimization rules are not documented, the language spec relies on it following the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/as_if).  In other words, you just can't tell whether or not it avoids executing a method.  Other than by the speedup or looking at the machine code.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I understand (and sometimes use) a code pattern like `shouldActivate || SomeMethod()` when `shouldActivate` is a feature flag, but not the other way around - when the method is on the left side of the `||` operator it will **always** be call because that's the order of evaluation in c#. What I don't understand is the `Method() || true;`

Comment: Say, for a grammar fragment like `IfStatement :== 'if' Exp StmtBlk ['else' StmtBlk] ;`, a parser generator might (simplified) generate a recognizer for that, which is something along the lines of, `bool IsIfStatement() => IsIf() && (IsElse() || true);`. If the optional else part is found, `IsElse()` advances the input pointer, otherwise not.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm asking because I'm interested in the answer. I was refactoring some code and removed a line like this to something more verbose but easy to reason about.

Comment: @ZoharPeled It's a simplification of a code listing from a project. It might not be best but it captures the gist.

Comment: @MartyIX the "line like this" wasn't working, unless it was reversed: `true || someMethod()`;. Depending on what the real code looked like, you could use pattern matching and a switch expression or statement to simplify *multiple* such "flags" and complex expressions. Or create a simple state machine based on the conditions, eg `(flag1,flag2,flag3) switch{ (true,_,_)=>, (_,true,false)=>....}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, why? There are better, more expressive ways to create eg functional feature flags.

In C#, both `&&` and `||` short-circuit on the left side only. This is explicitly mentioned in [12.14 Conditional logical operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12141-general).

This snippet won't short-circuit, as [this Sharplab.io example shows](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxBAzmAPgAQEwEYCwAUEZgMwAEO5AwuQN5HlOUWYAs5AsgBQCU9jZkOAB7EQBtyAJwCmKAK7iE5ALzkUIsDM4yEACxEATPuXTpyCKfJkBuQUKaZcATm6yFS3ncIPm98gC+/v6iEuqa2roGxrz+DD6+lADs5ABKEDCGmgB0AMp6ELKG2QByMgAeCCYApOTYKioADDaJ5P5BhAFAA===), not even in the JIT Assembly.

```
public class C {
    public void M() {
        bool result = someMethod() || true;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        
    }
    
    bool someMethod()
    {
        return Random.Shared.Next() % 2==0;        
    }
}
```

On the other hand, [the following call will be eliminated](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoTCDMACZPAYTwG9M9KD8EAWPAWQAoBKMiqz4Ae24Bs8AJwCmAZwCufAC54AvHimDxwvHDh5R3MMIbCpAC24ATVngDcHTpQQoAnExETpLCxitVLeAL6fPPfhpaOnqGJiye5G7uBADseABKEDBGWgB0AMr6ECJGqQBywgAeUqYApHhIsrIADGbReJ4+GF5AA===)

```
public class C {
    public void M() {
        bool result = true || someMethod() ;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        
    }
    
    bool someMethod()
    {
        return Random.Shared.Next() % 2==0;        
    }
}
```

The C# compiler will convert this to :

```
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(true);
    }

    private bool someMethod()
    {
        return Random.Shared.Next() % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "First of all, why?" while I understand your question, honestly, this is one reason I don't ask many questions on SO anymore. Anyway, the answer is: "I want to learn something new. Nothing more." Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @MartyIX on the contrary, `why` is the single most important question any professional can ask. Quite often it hides simpler solutions or a far wider problem that needs a very different approach. *Not* asking why is what typically results in constant rework, huge costs, disappointed customers and ... guess who's blamed?

Comment: @MartyIX as a simple example, a *lot* of SQL questions ask how to loop over this or that. That's almost always the wrong approach and a small SQL query will be both simpler and faster.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it will be always executed. This is not possible to optimize (i.e. remove the call to `someMethod`) in general case because `someMethod` can have a side-effect, i.e. changing some static variable, writing to some state storage, etc. (with the short-circuiting approach selected for C#).

> I'm just looking for a confirmation.

In addition to the referenced docs:

> The result of `x || y` is true if either `x` or `y` evaluates to true. Otherwise, the result is false. **If `x` evaluates to true**, `y` isn't evaluated.

i.e. the left-side will be short-circuited if the right side determines the result (not the other way around), i.e. right side is executed.

You can run something like the following (in Release mode):

```
bool result = someMethod() || true;
Console.WriteLine(result);

bool someMethod() {
    Console.WriteLine("someMethod");
    return true;
}
```

Which will print "someMethod" and "True" in succession.

[Demo @sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQ6BGB7bAbAAjAFMBnCPYAgXgNOwFtiBZY4AC2wBMAKASgIwYBYJGIBudHCQBOHiXKU+kjGhz46jFm068BAb3QFjBaXIBE9Jqw7dzyoybgB2EWJUBfdEA===)

And quote from the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12142-boolean-conditional-logical-operators):

> - The operation `x || y` is evaluated as `x ? true : y`. In other words, `x` is first evaluated and converted to type `bool`. Then, if `x` is `true`, the result of the operation is `true`. Otherwise, `y` is evaluated and converted to type `bool`, and this becomes the result of the operation.

Comment: Depends if you are talking about the C# compiler or the JIT. The JIT can indeed inline the whole thing.

Comment: Inlining isn't the same as eliminating the call. The C# specs say the call must always be made

Comment: Well it needs to *appear* to be made. The side effect needs to happen, it just doesn't have to happen via a method call. And if the method has no side effects then it will be eliminated completely. Here you go, no hands https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxBAzmAPgAQEwEYCwAUJgAwAEmuAdAEoCuMCUYAplQMID2YADlADYsATgGVhANygBjFigDcRIpgDMFbGXZkA3kTJ6KqzABYyAWQAUASm279d4J078yQ2XX4IyAXjIpuLUxYEAAtOABMrMnR0MgQhOhYFQjs7SgBOc1cUdwRLJJT9Wz0AXyKyMoBtQJDwgElefnNq0LD6nn4AeR4mThgUKgBBAHMhrJQocRZamH5YWCHLAF0yhydff2bwqzKdZIKKAHZY+MSy0sJioA

Answer (score 2):

While the evaluation of the boolean expression can be determined at compile time, the compiler has no idea what `someMethod()` does. If `someMethod()` has side effects, optimizing the expression would change the semantics of the code and thus the compiler cannot safely do this.